# Is there the following generalization of Goldbach's weak conjecture?

Tags: goldbachs-conjecture

I heard that the following has been proved: Every odd number greater than 7 can be expressed as the sum of three odd primes. What do we know about the following?

There is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb N$, $2n+1>7$ there exists primes $p_1,p_2,p_3$ such that $2n+1=p_1+p_2+p_3$ and $p_1<k$.

I mean, can we say that we can always represent all odd numbers greater than $7$ as a sum of three primes where the smallest prime is bounded by some constant.

Comment: Weaker result than even your "this has been proved": https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a *Goldbach number* to be an even integer that is the sum of two primes. Note that your statement is equivalent to the following: the gaps between consecutive Goldbach numbers is at most $k$ (perhaps even $k-3$). This is still an open problem, as mentioned in [this Terry Tao blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/the-parity-problem-obstruction-for-the-binary-goldbach-problem-with-bounded-error/). It is known (as [you can read about here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7_zFBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA507&lpg=PA507&dq=gaps%20between%20goldbach%20numbers&source=bl&ots=Lj_LHYMRWx&sig=872ovNMYOo1zsoqPLOwwS8cjN4g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_vcvm4IHPAhUIax4KHa5rC8UQ6AEIQzAG#v=onepage&q=gaps%20between%20goldbach%20numbers&f=false)) that you can replace the constant $k$ with a power of $\log n$ and the statement becomes true, which is close at least.